# Unable to override css class of Awesome-slider-react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using [Awesome-Slider-React](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-slider) to build a small web-app. I am facing an issue in styling my content. Awesome-Slider gives default styling to all the div defined inside `<AwesomeSlider>` which reduces the div you have access to very small size as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqYcn.png). I want to be able to place my components in the full screen. I tried overriding the class `awssld__content` but this only works if I supply `!important` in `App.css`. What is the best way for me to have access to the div which spans the whole viewport.

JSX

```
<AwesomeSlider cssModule={AwesomeSliderStyles}>
<div className = "main" style = {{ backgroundColor: "white" }}> <About/></div>
<div className = "main" style = {{ backgroundColor: "white"}} >
    <BarChart
      data={data}
      title={"check"}
      color="#70CAD1"
    />
    <LineChart
      data={data1}
      title={"check"}
      color="#70CAD1"
    />
</div>
<div>
  <Col lg="8" md="12" sm="12" className="mb-4">
    <UsersOverview />
  </Col>
</div> 
</AwesomeSlider>
```

App.css

```
.main {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: left;
}
.awssld__content {
  align-items: left ;
  justify-content: left !important;
}
```

SCSS file from Awesome-Slider. The complete code for the SCSS file can be seen [here.](https://github.com/rcaferati/react-awesome-slider/blob/master/src/core/styles.scss)

```
  &__content {
    @extend %fill-parent;
    background-color: var(--content-background-color);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    > img,
    > video {
      object-fit: cover;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    &--enter {
      // On content enter
    }
    &--exit {
      // On content exit
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge.

One way is to refer to the .scss (SASS) stylesheet instead of the .css in the /dist folder. The latest is the uglified build version of the SASS stylesheets.

```
//import 'react-awesome-slider/dist/styles.css';
import 'react-awesome-slider/src/styles.js';
```

You also need to configure a sass-loader in your React app (install node-sass and sass-loader).

The downside of this, I guess, is that the SASS file gets tranpsiled reel-time. This probably costs performance ... so not sure if this is the best practise for production.

It should also be possible to transpile the customized SASS file, so the /DIST version will be updated. I tried this myself, but didn't manage to get this to work. Maybe someone knows how to do this?

One last thing: I use webpack for building and loading my react app. There was an error due to a conflict in the versions of webpack (4.41.5) and sass-loader (8.x). The error was `TypeError: this.getResolve ...`. The fix I found was downgrading sass-loader to 7.3.1.

Good luck